# Visualising the last layer node embeddings of a model in torch geometric

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I'm doing my first graph convolutional neural network project with `torch_geometric`. I want to visualize the last layer node embeddings of my model and don't know how I should get it.

I trained my model on the CiteSeer dataset. You can get the full dataset as easily as this:

```
from torch_geometric.datasets import Planetoid
from torch_geometric.transforms import NormalizeFeatures
dataset = Planetoid(root="data/Planetoid", name='CiteSeer', transform=NormalizeFeatures())
```

My model is a simple two-layered model as this:

```
class GraphClassifier(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dataset, hidden_dim):
        super(GraphClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(dataset.num_features, hidden_dim)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_dim, dataset.num_classes)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x, edge_index))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x, edge_index))
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

If you print my model you will get this:

```
model = GraphClassifier(dataset, 64)
print(model)

>>>
GraphClassifier(
  (conv1): GCNConv(3703, 64)
  (conv2): GCNConv(64, 6)
)
```

My model is trained successfully. I only want to visualize its last-layer node embeddings. To visualize that I have this function to use:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import torch
# emb: (nNodes, hidden_dim)
# node_type: (nNodes,). Entries are torch.int64 ranged from 0 to num_class - 1

def visualize(emb: torch.tensor, node_type: torch.tensor):
  z = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(emb.detach().cpu().numpy())
  plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
  plt.scatter(z[:, 0], z[:, 1], s=70, c=node_type, cmap="Set2")
  plt.show()
```

I don't know how I should extract `emb` and `node_type` from my model to give to the `visualize` function. `emb` is the last layer of node embeddings of the model. How can I get these from my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solve by changing the model to this:

```
class GraphClassifier(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dataset, hidden_dim):
        super(GraphClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(dataset.num_features, hidden_dim)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_dim, dataset.num_classes)

    def forward(self, data, do_visualize=False):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x, edge_index))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x, edge_index))
        if do_visualize:                          # NEW LINE
            visualize(x, data.y)                  # NEW LINE
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

Now if you call the forward function with `do_visualize=Ture` it will visualize. like this:

```
model = GraphClassifier(dataset, hidden_dim)
model.to(device)
model(dataset[0].to(device), do_visualize=True)
```